# Creating explosion-based tremor artifacts

Tags: live-performance, sound-effects-recording, sound-editing

Hi guys, I've got a project on at the moment where the main focus is on a group of soldier holed up in Afghan bunker. During many of the scenes, the sound of mortar coming down on them remains constant. The detonation start distant and begin to zero in over the course of the play. Thanks to a great little library from EFX Audio as well as The Whoosh from Tonsturm, I've got the actual mortar shots and detonations sorted.

What I'm trying to achieve now are the the little nuances created by distant tremors in the ground. Things like unsettled dust, creaking fixtures and crumbling plaster. I've managed to replicate some of this by slowly pouring rice onto a plastic lid but I'm looking for a little more variety now that the mortars are persistent throughout the storyline.

Any tricks or techniques to achieve these subtle sounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there are any tricks to getting this sort of stuff. Just record it.

Why not just buy a large sheet or two of drywall from the hardware store and bash and tear away for the plaster and dust? Go outside to a patch of dry dirt and record close mic-ed sledgehammer hits on the ground. Find your favorite piece of old wood furniture and twist away for the creaks. Get a large subwoofer and send low rumbles through it and record the results interacting with different spaces.

Good luck.

Comment: I was hoping the answer would involve some mindless destructions ;)